# What is an alternative to <iframe> for Stack Exchange websites when we want to embed a Google nGram?

Tags: support

Stack Exchange allows a limited subset of HTML in Markdown. The full description of what parts of HTML are allowed on Stack Exchange can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/542513).

I was trying to embed a [Google nGram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer). However, I am not sure if the `<iframe>` html tag is still supported.

What went wrong here?

```html
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=swim+team%2Cswimming+team&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cswim%20team%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cswimming%20team%3B%2Cc0" width=900 height=500 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't think `<iframe>` has ever been allowed. Why do you think it was?

Comment: During the grace period did you edit to insert the 1st paragraph? Is it supposed to be an answer? Answers belong in answer posts & not question posts. Otherwise why is it there? PS Please research before considering posting question. PS Please format code reasonably.

Answer (score 6):

You can't embed an iframe, but you can take the URL from it, remove `interactive_` and put that as the image URL:

[image: describe the graph here]

Markdown:

`![describe the graph here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=swim+team%2Cswimming+team&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cswim%20team%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cswimming%20team%3B%2Cc0)`

But this has little to no advantage over uploading via the SE image uploader.